# How to find last shown value in while loop?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to check if the `reason` and `id` are same when I am fetching the info from database through while loop.

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE `to`=:my_id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10";
    $query = $db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array(
        ":my_id" => $my_id
    ));
    while ($row = $query->fetchObject()) {
        $from = $row->from;
        $reason = $row->reason;
        $text = $row->text;
        $link_id = $row->link_id;
    }
?>
```

Now, what I want is when the reason of the last shown notification and the current showing notification are same then they must be shown as one.

Comment: [careful with that `to`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) - it's erroring out [but you're not seeing the error.](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php)

Comment: Sorry, it was added in the real code but, I forgot to add it here.

Comment: i think it's not very clear what you're trying to do

Comment: `if($var1 == $var2){...}` basically, inside your loop.